# Within JetBrains DataSpell Jupyter Notebook IPython.Display.SVG Images are not displayed fully/cut off

Tags: python, jupyter, ipython, jetbrains-ide, dataspell

I am using DataSpell to work in a Jupyter Notebook with an conda environment. When I try to display a IPython.display.SVG graphic, it is not rendered correctly and parts are cut off.

I am following along this [tutorial](https://scikit-network.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/clustering/louvain.html#Directed-graphs).
When I use the SVG function imported from
`from IPython.display import SVG`
I expect to see a full image. Instead it is cut off like this:

[image: How the SVG is displayed in dataspell]

It worked fine when I tested it directly in the Jupyter Web Interface. There I got the expected results:

[image: How the SVG is displayed in Jupyter Web]

I would be really thankful if anybody can share how to display the SVG images in DataSpell correctly.

Comment: Maybe try matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()?

Comment: I have found out, that there must be an issue with the viewBox. The function sknetwork.visualization.graphs.svg_graph does not add one to the generated svg string. As a workaround I will probably add this attribute manually.